# Graphic Issues after upgrading to 23.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, display-resolution, amdgpu

Since upgrading to 23.10 I can't change my display resolution on my laptop.

Lenovo Yoga Slim 7 Pro 14ACH5
AMD Ryzen™ 9 5900HX with Radeon™ Graphics × 16

It only works on the default resolution 2880x1800 (16:10). I have options for other resolutions in settings but when switching to any of them the display glitches out see the image attached. I don't have any options for using additional display drivers.

I'm also getting some weird graphic malfunctions when using software that uses opengl. The display flickers and kind of breaks down into polygons. Once I close the software the effect usually stops.

All attempts to solve this on my own by installing other amd drivers hasn't helped, so i've removed any additional driver packages (like kisak-mesa) that I was using in 23.04. I had no problems when using 23.04. I could switch to 1920x1200 which is my preferred resolution.

[image]